# Output to two different files using Flex and Bison

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I would like to print the tokens generated by Flex in file_1 and print the parsed output generated by Bison in file_2. Currently, I am printing them both into a single file so they are mixed up together. How do I separate the printing into two different files?

I've tried printing them separately by calling yylex then yyparse but it did not work.

Below is my Flex and Bison file.

**Flex file**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Parser.tab.h"
%}

Number [0-9]*[\.0-9]*
Ident  [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*
Tagident  <[A-Za-z]+
Whitespace  [ \t\n]+
Comment  <!--(.*?)-->
Plus  \+
Minus  \-
Mult  \*
Divide  \/
Modulo  \%
Exp  [*]{2}
Lparen  \(
Rparen  \)
Equals  \=
Lthan  \<
Gthan  \>
Colon  \:
Comma  \,
Scolon \;
Period \s+\.\s+
Quote \'                                                                                                                            
Dquote \"                                                                                                                                           
Endtaghead <[/]                                                                                                             

%%
\n  {/* Do nothing */}
{Comment}   {/* Do nothing */}
{Whitespace}    {/* Do nothing */}
{Number} {printf("%s%s%s", "Number\t\t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.ival= atoi(yytext); return number; }
{Plus}  {printf("%s%s%s", "Plus\t\t" ,yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return plus; }
{Minus} {printf("%s%s%s", "Minus \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return minus; }
{Mult}  {printf("%s%s%s", "Mult \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return mult; }
{Divide} {printf("%s%s%s", "Divide\t\t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return divide; }
{Modulo} {printf("%s%s%s", "Modulo \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return modulo; }
{Exp} {printf("%s%s%s", "Exp \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return exp;}
{Lparen} {printf("%s%s%s", "Lparen \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return left; }
{Rparen} {printf("%s%s%s", "Rparen \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return right; }
{Equals} {printf("%s%s%s", "Equals \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return equals; }
{Lthan} {printf("%s%s%s", "Lthan\t\t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);return lthan; }
{Gthan} {printf("%s%s%s", "Gthan\t\t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return gthan; }
{Colon} {printf("%s%s%s", "Colon \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);return colon;}
{Comma} {printf("%s%s%s", "Comma \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);return comma; }
{Scolon} {printf("%s%s%s", "Scolon \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);return scolon; }
{Period} {printf("%s%s%s", "Period \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);return period;}
{Quote} {printf("%s%s%s", "Quote \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);return quote; }
{Dquote} {printf("%s%s%s", "Dquote \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);return dquote;}
{Ident} {printf("%s%s%s", "Ident\t\t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);return ident; }
{Tagident} {printf("%s%s%s", "Tagident \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);return tagident;}
{Endtaghead} {printf("%s%s%s", "Endtaghead \t", yytext,"\n"); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);return endtaghead; }
. {printf("%s%s%s", "Invalid character \t", yytext,"\n"); }

%%
int yywrap (void ) 
{
    return 1;
}
```

**Parser file**

```
%{
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  extern int yylex();
  extern int yyparse();
  extern FILE *yyin;
  extern FILE *yyout;
  void yyerror(const char *s);
%}

%union{
  int ival;
  char *sval; 
}

/* Some tokens are unused since program is not yet complete */
%token <ival> number
%token <sval> ident
%token <sval> tagident
%token <sval> endtaghead
%token <sval> plus 
%token <sval> minus
%token <sval> mult
%token <sval> divide
%token <sval> modulo
%token <sval> left
%token <sval> right 
%token <sval> equals
%token <sval> lthan
%token <sval> gthan
%token <sval> colon
%token <sval> comma 
%token <sval> scolon
%token <sval> period
%token <sval> quote
%token <sval> dquote
%token <sval> exp


%error-verbose

%start summary
%%

summary: opener rows closer
;

opener: tagident gthan
;

closer: endtaghead ident gthan
;

rows: row | row rows
;

row: opener cells closer
;

cells: cell | cell cells
;

cell: opener contents closer
;

contents: content | content contents
;

content: ident 
{
  printf("%s",$1);
}
;


content: number
{
  printf("%d",$1);
}
;


%%
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #ifdef YYDEBUG
    yydebug = 1;
    #endif
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    yyout = freopen(argv[2], "w",stdout);
    fprintf(yyout, "%s%s","TOKEN\t\t","LEXEME\n");   
    fprintf(yyout, "-------------------------------------------------\n");
    if(yyparse() ==0)
    {
        fprintf(yyout,"Parse success");
    }
    fclose(yyin);
    fclose(yyout);
}
void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);     
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? The way the question is written makes it look a lot like homework :)

Comment: `yyout` is a global variable, not a function. And neither `bison` nor `flex` requires its use.

Comment: I've added my code

Comment: `printf` prints to stdout. Always. So the value of `yyout` is irrelevant to all your calls to `printf`. If you want to print to a different file, use `fopen` to open the file and then `fprintf` to print to it. If you want to print to two different files, fopen both of them and select which one to print to in each fprintf. Your use of yyout here seems pointless to me. Also, you almost never need the string value of an operator token, since you know what string it is. Tokens only need to have semantic values if you're going to use that value in some rule.